How to best approach a numerical computational solution towards matching $e^{-r}$ and $k_2\sin(k_1\,r)$ as well as their derivatives $\frac{d}{d\,r}$?
In my question, "Why does it seem like two parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$ are needed to match $e^{-r}$ and $k_2\sin(k_1\,r)$ as well as their derivatives $\frac{d}{d\,r}$?", it was identified that two parameters $\left(k_2\right)$ and $\left(k_1 \, r -\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ were needed to provide a good match with minimum error.

The Spherical Bessel functions that solve the Spherical Helmholtz equation in the Spherical Coordinate system come in four kinds, the Spherical Bessel Functions of the first kind, the Spherical Bessel Functions of the second kind.  The fundamental (propagating) functions are of the form $j_0(r)=\frac{\sin(r)}{r}$, $n_0(r)=\frac{-\cos(r)}{r}$.  In addition, by applying Euler's identity that through a linear combination (using scale factors that include $\sqrt{-1}$) that there are indeed two additional (evanescent) solutions of the form $\frac{e^{-r}}{r}$ and $\frac{e^{r}}{r}$ which are suitable only for $r\ne 0$.  Applying the Lemma below that "If $\left. a(r)\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. b(r)\right|_{r=r_0}$
and $\left. \frac{\partial a(r)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{ \partial b(r)}{\partial r}\right|_{r=r_0}$ then $\left. \frac{a(r)}{r}\right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{b(r)}{r}\right|_{r=r_0} $ and $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ a(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0} = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \frac{ b(r)}{r} \right|_{r=r_0}$ for $r_0 \ne 0$" applying boundary conditions of equal value $r=r_0$ at the boundary and also equal value can be solved numerically using two scaling factors $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $\left.(k_2) j_0(k_1 r)\right|_{r=r_0}=\left.\frac{e^{-r}}{r}\right|_{r=r_0}$.  Further, by applying the below Lemma, this task is simplified to applying the same boundary conditions on $\left. (k_2) \sin(k_1 r)\right|_{r=r_0}$ and $\left.e^{-r}\right|_{r=r_0}$, where application of the Lemma proves that the boundary conditions on the simpler functions prove the same boundary function on the more complex equations.  Plus the simpler formula has many references to solving the equivalent Schrodinger particle in a potential box problem.
From a plot from this reference, it seems that there is one bound state that might be nearly a quarter wavelength from the origin wide:






However, with a hand solution (with the assistance of a spreadsheet), it seemed that these parameters could have considerable adjustment with similar minimal error results.  These were calculated by use of a spreadsheet, and had an error on the order of $10^{-7}$, which seemed good.
However, perhaps there is something fundamental about these constants.  Also, perhaps it is better to derive a solution using $\frac1{k_2}$ because it is multiplied by a small number to equal one.
So the question is: "How to best approach a numerical computational solution towards matching $e^{-r}$ and $k_2\sin(k_1\,r)$ as well as their derivatives $\frac{d}{d\,r}$?"
Mathematical Considerations
To see if this was a correct approach, a first attempt was made with just a single scaling parameter $k_1\,r-\frac{pi}{2}$.  However, introduction of a second scaling parameter $k_2$ was necessary to make it possible to reach a good match of the value and the slope at a good match-point $r$ as well as the range for $k_1 \, r$ being $\frac{\pi}{2}<k_1 \, r < \pi $.  Thus because of this necessity the new functions being matched are:
$$
k_2\,sin(k_1\,r)=e^{-r} \underset{implies} \implies k_2\,sin(\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2})=e^{-r}
\\ \underset{implies}\implies
k_2\,cos(\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=e^{-r}
$$
$$
k_2\,sin(k_1\,r)=e^{-r} \underset{implies} 
\implies
k_2\,k_1\,cos(k_1\,r)=-e^{-r}
\underset{implies} 
\implies
k_1\,\frac{cos(k_1\,r)}{sin(k_1\,r)}=-1
$$
Using the identities for $cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ then
$$
k_1\,\frac{\displaystyle \cos\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
{\displaystyle \sin\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=-1
$$
The substitution of the identities are then made:
$$
k_1\,\frac{\displaystyle \sin\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
{\displaystyle \cos\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}=1
$$
And hence there are the functions with the two scaling parameters necessary to make a good match.  Also, because $\frac{\displaystyle \sin\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
{\displaystyle \cos\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$ is small, for computational optimizations it might be better to optimize the parameter:
$$
\frac1{k_1} =\frac{\displaystyle \sin\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
{\displaystyle \cos\left(k_1\,r-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}
$$
Numerical Computational Approaches Towards a Solution
I was considering using a neural network that was carefully designed to avoid local minima that seemed to plague the hand-minimization approach.
What is the best method to arrive at these fundamental constants?
Motivation
I am looking to arrive at an answer that can help me solve for the bare mass of the electron as well as the corresponding stored electromagnetic energy to arrive at a calculation for the rest mass of the electron, from a different question where I had calculated the ionization energy of Helium to $0.3\%$, but I was still wondering how to improve that calculation, as well as to explain a model for the bare mass of the electron and also its corresponding energy stored in the Electrostatic Fields.
So I cannot afford errors in the calculated scaling parameters $k_2$ and $k_1 \, r -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and therefore I want to use a numerical computational approach to get at an absolute result, rather than relying on hand-adjustments.
I appreciate any suggestions and help.
Steps Towards a Computational Solution
I have researched neural networks, and the approach seems interesting to me of using them, since it might be possible to introduce a noise term to avoid getting caught in local minima.  The hand spreadsheet approach seemed to get caught up in local minima.  Also, three-dimensional plots (like from Desmos) in the local solution region may help identify the proper final constant calculations and adjustments.

I'm a bit confused: are we matching them at some prescribed point $r_0$ or is $r_0$ also free to choose? If the latter, then we have an underdetermined problem, so what are we minimizing? (you talked about "local minima" but I'm not completely sure of what exactly)
